# How to set different header for the group thread request in apache jmeter?

Tags: multithreading, performance, jmeter, load-testing, database-concurrency

I want to test concurrency of application, I'm using apache Jmeter for that, the endpoint I'm requesting,  needs to have authorization header for authentication, in apache Jmeter HTTP Header Manager i have added a header with the name Authorization with the token value, now lets say I have 5 number of threads (users), when the test runs all the 5 users request with the same authorization token, I want each thread to request with the different token, to simulate the different users and not multiple instances of one user, I hope the question makes sense, How can I make each thread request the api with different token? that is unique header value for each thread's request.
Thanks love you guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have 5 different users - you need to have 5 different tokens. You can put the tokens into i.e. a CSV file and add [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to your Test Plan

[image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]

Once done you will be able to access each entry of the CSV file (which will be different for each thread/iteration) as `${token}` in the [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

[image: JMeter HTTP Header Manager Variable]

Check out [JMeter Parameterization - The Complete Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide) article to learn more about the concept of performing data-driven tests using various external data sources like CSV files, databases, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, that really helped,I loved this tool.

Comment: Very useful answer Thanks a lot